# boot.img for android aosp is not getting generated

Tags: android

all

I have tried building android aosp , but the boot.img file is not getting generated. I have tried rebuilding it again but still its the same.

I need the flash the image through sd card but the image is no getting generated.

regards,
delsy

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.